# How to vertical align <a> inside list with variable height?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

### I'd like to vertically align my anchor tags inside my list, but there is a problem.

The number of list items are variable to the number of pages my website has. So I set a display flex on the list and flex: 1 on the list items. Every list item contains an anchor tag to redirect to that certain page. It looks weird because they are vertically aligned to the top of the list item (while the list items all have the same height to fill up the 100% height of the  thanks to flex).

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
li:first-child {
  background-color: #35CE93;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #3A999F;
}
li:last-child {
  background-color: #59ADEB;
}
li {
  display: block;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

One solution would be to have another span inside the anchor tag and put the anchor tag to a relative position and the span on absolute.
But I can't edit the way the list shows up because I use it on mulitple sites that don't need a span or it will bug.

I could force the spans to go inside the list items with jQuery but I rather not do that.

**UPDATE**
adding this will fix it on computers, but not on iPhone:

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Align them vertically using pseudo elements while using `inline-block` for the anchor tags in your `li` as below:

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

a:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
}
```

snippet below:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
li:first-child {
  background-color: #35CE93;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #3A999F;
}
li:last-child {
  background-color: #59ADEB;
}
li {
  display: block;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

check this out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

**Flexbox solution:**

Also check if changing the `li` in your code as per below will work in iphone to center the `a` using `flexbox` techniques:

```
li {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

snippet below:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
li:first-child {
  background-color: #35CE93;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #3A999F;
}
li:last-child {
  background-color: #59ADEB;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman let me know if this works for you? Thanks!

Comment: wow thanks! I only had to add "a { width: 100%; }"! Thanks for the help and quick respond!

Comment: the weird thing is.. On iPhone it doesn't work...

Comment: Try adding a `position: relative` to the `a:before` ?

Comment: no that didn't make a difference @kukkuz the website is dotvoip.nl by the way (still in dev)

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman don't have an iphone to test here. Try the alternate solution I have added to the answer above? Thanks!

Comment: I will check that. Haven't been online today, so I will let you know tomorrow

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman didn't get your feedback on this. is everything working fine now?

Comment: Yeah sorry! No I wasn't able to solve it for safari iOs, but I "fixed" it with padding-bottom for the ul. Still looks good

Comment: cool... maybe the `flexbox` solution I have given above may come in handy. :) Please upvote / accept the answer if you found it useful. Thanks!

Comment: I found it very useful! I'd love to upvote, but I dont have >15 reputation yet :(

Comment: ohh, that's cool... just commented like I do for all the answers I make in SO :)

Comment: Thank you man! You're really helpful

Comment: Got 15 rep thanks to an upvote, i upvoted your answer ;)